# Display fields from foreign key linked model django

Tags: python, django, api

So I've created an API with the Django rest framework. I have a simple model relationship which is, User -> Posts. Users are linked to the posts because the user is the AUTHOR of a post. All I want to do is display the username associated with a POST in my rest API. How do I reference other fields from a model that I linked as a foreign key? IF I have a user model that has a username, profile picture and email, how can I display those in my Post model???

Here is an example of what I am trying to do with the models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.mp4', upload_to='video_thumbnails')
    videoFile = models.FileField(default='default.mp4', upload_to='videos')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , #Something to get the username here, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Right now this displays

```
 {
        "title": "HOLROYD SWIPE ACCESS(CS ROOMS)",
        "content": "Yeet",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/video_thumbnails/Screenshot_from_2019-08-03_23-37-50.png",
        "videoFile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/videos/Screenshot_from_2019-08-03_23-37-52.png",
        "date_posted": "2019-10-22T21:01:07Z",
        "user": 1
    }
```

All I want it to do is display the name of the user instead of the USER ID which is 1 in this case.

I JUST want it to look like this instead

```
 {
        "title": "HOLROYD SWIPE ACCESS(CS ROOMS)",
        "content": "Yeet",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/video_thumbnails/Screenshot_from_2019-08-03_23-37-50.png",
        "videoFile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/videos/Screenshot_from_2019-08-03_23-37-52.png",
        "date_posted": "2019-10-22T21:01:07Z",
        "user": "usernameassociatedwithpost" 
    }
```

Here is my serializer

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'image', 'videoFile', 'date_posted', 'user' )
```

and here is my views.py

```
class VideoList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer


class VideoDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
```

If anymore code is needed to answer this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Show your serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I shared my serialized and views. Is there anything else I should share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="username", queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'image', 'videoFile', 'date_posted', 'user' )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked. Would I do the same thing if I wanted to reference fields from other models?